# How to combine AJAX + view function (API call) + url mapping the smart way?

Tags: python, django, ajax, python-requests

I have a Javascript function that assigns the team_id of a soccer team to a variable on 'click' of the teams name in the sidebar (see below for a screenshot).
This variable shall then be used to make the according API call to get fresh data to update the dashboard as requested. The web application/dashboard is Django based.

The Javascript itself assigns the variable smoothly and the views function itself fetches data from the API as well (when using a fix API URL without the assigned variable).

To make this thread a future guidance for similar issues, i divided the content in different questions and tried to present it as neat as possibe.

**1.)** 
 Now when I want to combine these steps i always end up with a TypeError (because the API call doesn't return any data) since the views function seems not to use the assigned variable 'team_id' within the API url (the team_id is emtpy when debugging = no API data in return). Why is that?

**2.)** 
 I also tried to change the logic of the url mapping that way (which I would prefer) that there is only one url e.g. www.dasocc.com to display the dashboard and the user won't be redirected if he selects a different soccerteam in the sidebar. But here I have the issue that I need to map the `team_update` view function to the index.html which then can't be rendered at all because there can't be a variable assigned in first place (chicken or egg paradox).
Might it be senseful to expand the views function with a conditional statement like ("If there is no team_id value assigned, use team_id = 70) to avoid an empty API call and therefor the website to render at all?

**3.)** 
 Is there a way to only activate the views `team_update` function when the user clicks a team in the sidebar? That way I could avoid to run the function without an assigned variable team_id.

**4.)** 
 Do I need to use the AJAX success function to render the page with the returned data besides the view function which itself renders anyways?

I am so close to bring the dashboard to live. I hope you guys can help me with the final steps to make the ''user click - API call - dashboard update'' application work.

**Error**

```
TypeError at /dashboard/
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/
Django Version: 2.2.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
Exception Location: C:\Users\Jonas Blickle\Desktop\dasocc\dasocc_site\dasocc_app\views.py in team_update, line 16
Python Executable:  C:\Users\JONASB~1\Envs\DASOCC~1\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.4
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Jonas\\Desktop\\dasocc\\dasocc_site',
 'C:\\Users\\JONASB~1\\Envs\\DASOCC~1\\Scripts\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\JONASB~1\\Envs\\DASOCC~1\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\JONASB~1\\Envs\\DASOCC~1\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\JONASB~1\\Envs\\DASOCC~1\\Scripts',
 'c:\\users\\jonas\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\Lib',
 'c:\\users\\jonas '
 'blickle\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\JONASB~1\\Envs\\DASOCC~1',
 'C:\\Users\\JONASB~1\\Envs\\DASOCC~1\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 2 Oct 2019 12:27:08 -0500
```

**Javascript/AJAX:**

```
$('ul.subbar li a').on('click', function(e) {
var team_id = $(this).attr("id");
console.log(team_id);
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "/dashboard/",
  data: {'team': team_id},
  success: function() {

    }
  });
});
```

**views.py function**

```
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render
import json

def team_update(request):
    team_id = request.GET.get('team')
    response = requests.get(f'http://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/teams/team/{team_id}')
    team_data = response.json()
    teams = team_data.get('api', {}).get('teams', [])
    if teams and len(teams) == 1:
        teams = teams[0]
    return render(request, 'index.html', {
        'name': teams['name'],
        'country': teams['country'],
        'founded': teams['founded'],
        'logo': teams['logo'],
        'venue_capacity': teams['venue_capacity'],
    })
```

**urls mapping**

```
from dasocc_app import views
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.render_landing_page, name='landing_page'),
    url(r'admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'about/', views.render_about),
    url(r'dashboard/', views.team_update, name='team'),
    url(r'dasocc_app/', include('dasocc_app.urls'))
]
```

[image]

Comment: please show us the `team_data` (`response.json()`) that you get back from the API. Also, since you log `team_id` in your javascript to console, you should be able to tell if it's empty or not before actually reaching your view.

Comment: Finally, an ajax request just fetches data from the API (and doesn't do anything with that data by itself). You need to program in js what to do with that data in the `success` function. Your view is returning the fully rendered index.html page, which makes no sense. Either remove the javascript altogether and just make each team a normal link to your view (refreshing the entire page, that's what your view does). Or make a view that returns the data to be filled in the table and write your success function to parse the data and fill each cell of the table (tedious).